# Use colmap with GPU but no attached display inside Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, computer-vision, vision

I have an issue with the feature_extraction feature from colmap when using it inside docker container. Since there is no display inside the container, I need to turn off GPU like mentioned [here](https://colmap.github.io/faq.html#available-functionality-without-gpu-cuda)

```
--SiftExtraction.use_gpu=false
```

Is there any way to use GPU inside docker ?

Thank you

Comment: mm I am not an expert but I don't think that is what it means. It does not matter if you have a display "inside the container" (what does that mean?). I am using colmap on a workstation without display but WITH Gpu of course, so I use the GPU(no need to turn it off)

Comment: Answering your other question, it is supposedly a way to use the GPU inside docker, but unfortunately due to difference in drivers I haven't been able to do it. However my colleague did it and I am now using his container without problems